# General tips for representing large numbers

Tags: code-golf, number, tips

Sometimes, while golfing, one needs to represent large number(s) in their code. Writing them as is can significantly increase the byte-count.

What *general*<sup>1</sup> tips do you have for representing long numbers concisely in code?

Please post one tip per answer.

---

<sup>1</sup>With *general*, I mean tips that can be applied to more than a single language. For language-specific tips, post in their respective thread.

Comment: [Related.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/70167/8478)

Comment: [Also related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/57905/32686)

Comment: I saw someone misunderstanding the question - perhaps the title should say this is about golfing.

Comment: [Also also related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/54785/shortening-a-long-number)

Answer (score 15):

## Look out for special numbers

Some languages have built-in functions for squares, exponentiation with base 2, *n*-th prime, factorial, or other procedures that can generate large numbers. Check if you number *happens to fall* into any of those categories.

And if it doesn't, it may happen that a *larger* number that does will fit for your purposes and can be used instead.

Comment: Even if the number you want cannot be generated with a builtin function, it may be possible to generate a number that you can use as the basis for a simple calculation to arrive at your number, while still saving bytes over writing it out.

Comment: +1 for "larger number" -- if `1.01e6` iterations is enough, `1e7` saves 3 bytes at the expense of running time.

Answer (score 13):

## Use bitwise boolean operators

Some languages have bitwise AND, OR, XOR, and sometimes NOT.

Expressing a specific large number as a bitwise combination of a result of an exponentiation or left shift and another number can get you to precisely the number you need. This is usually only worth it if the numbers get quite big.

For example, `2147483722` is 10 bytes, but `2<<30^74` (2^31 bitwise-XORed with 74) is only 8.

Comment: The shift operator can be replaced with exponentiation, if the language has that operator (eg `bc`). And XOR is never more useful than `+` and `-`: in this case, xor and add give the same result, but in all cases there is some integer which can be added or subtracted to produce the same result as xor with an integer, and the addend is no larger and sometimes shorter.

Comment: @rici True if all integers are written as simple decimals, but it's just possible the integer to be used with xor can be shortened in ways that the integer to be used with plus or minus can't: think of something like `1e9^2e9`.

Comment: @rici How would you express `9<<49^7<<19` using addition instead of xor?

Comment: @rici No, I meant what I wrote. It evaluates to `1286561280` in JavaScript and Perl (and probably other languages), and it's a shorter expression to produce that value than the equivalent using `+` or `-`.

Comment: @hvd: OK, point taken.

Answer (score 11):

### Use Scientific Notation

Scientific notation can save bytes in case of long numbers. For Example:

```
3564e-8 // returns 0.00003564 (saves 3 bytes!)
```

Comment: Why not just use `3564e-8` in that case?

Comment: @Joey Yes, of course! Thank you! :)

Comment: Granted, you can usually write the other number as `.00003564`, which is also one byte shorter again.

Comment: @Joey Not every language does, hence, I won't edit that in.

Comment: Is it intentional that 3564 (left) becomes 354 (right) or is that a typo?

Comment: @Erik Typo. Thanks for pointing that out! :)

Answer (score 11):

### Use Strings for repetitive numbers

For numbers that are very repetitive in nature, you can use Strings and cast them to Integer. For Example, in JavaScript

```
+"1".repeat(100) // returns 100 1s (saves 84 bytes!)
```

Comment: Or you could use a very large fraction, `1e100/9` in this case.

Answer (score 10):

### Base Compression

Base decompression code can be fairly complex, but if you have a truly enormous number sometimes it can help to compress it in some base higher than 10.

It also helps that in some languages, the base compression code is very simple. For example, PHP has `base64_decode(_)`, Python has `int(_,36)`, JavaScript has `parseInt(_,36)`, and many golfing languages have base decompression builtins.
For example, in CJam:

```
"+ÜTbô±"256b
```

This contains an unprintable. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/cjam#@6@kfXhOSNKhiYe3HNqoZGRqlvT/PwA)

This yields:

```
12345678987654321
```

Answer (score 10):

## Look for another number to use instead

This may sound like a non-answer, but it is not always obvious that a larger number can be calculated by shorter code. An example I remember is [Output a googol copies of a string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/97975/output-a-googol-copies-of-a-string), where the obvious answers require computing 10<sup>100</sup>. As it turns out, computing any multiple of 10<sup>100</sup> leads to an equally correct, but in some languages, shorter answer. Dennis's answer there uses 100<sup>100</sup>, my own uses 250<sup>255</sup>.

Comment: Another example of this is CJam where you can get the current timestamp with `es` if you just need a large number but don't care about its value (or that it's always the same).

Answer (score 9):

### Use Bitwise Left Shift for 2's exponentiation

Although, there are many languages that support operator for exponentiation, some do not. And those which don't, usually require calling functions (or Class/Object methods), which can cost a few bytes.

But you can save some bytes when you need to raise 2 to the power *n* by using the Bitwise Left Shift operator `<<` as `1<<n`. Note that this will only save you bytes if *n* is greater than or equal to 17. However, this will *always* save you bytes if *n* is dynamic. Few Examples:

```
1<<2 // returns 4 (3 bytes more :( )
1<<3 // returns 8 (3 bytes more :( )
1<<6 // returns 64 (2 bytes more :( )
1<<14 // returns 16384 (no bytes saved)
1<<17 // returns 131072 (saves 1 byte!)
1<<18 // returns 262114 (saves 1 byte!)
```

Comment: Note that you can use other values instead of 1.  `8<<9 // 4096` so we can get up to `99<<61` in 6 bytes, which equals `6,917,529,027,641,081,856` saving 13 bytes!

Comment: @Draco18s Yes, and it's covered [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/123435/general-tips-for-representing-large-numbers/123442#123442).

Comment: That one more covers the boolean bitwise operators. Yes, it has the bitshifting too, but it's talking about using two large numbers to XOR and get a third, specific number.

Answer (score 9):

### Use exponential fractions for large repetitive numbers

Say you wanted to generate the number made of 100 1's. You could use `int("1"*100)`, `+"1".repeat(100)`, etc. but you can also take advantage of the fact that it's very close to

```
1e100/9
```

This works best for very repetitive numbers, such as those made of a single digit. A couple repeated digits also works fairly well:

```
12e100/99  // Generates 121212121212... (100 digits)
```

Occasionally you'll find some other weird pattern which also can be represented fairly tersely in this method. If you happened to need `int("123456790"*11)`, for example:

```
1e100/81
```

Be careful, though: numbers such as `int("1234567890"*10)` don't have such an easy representation.

Answer (score 8):

## Chinese Remainder Theorem

If arbitrary big integers frequently appear, or big integer representation in target programming language costs too many bytes, you can consider using Chinese Remainder Theorem.

Choose some pairwise relatively prime integers m<sub>i</sub> >=2, and you can express a big number from 0 to lcm(m<sub>1</sub>, m<sub>2</sub>, ... , m<sub>i</sub>) -1

For example, I choose 2, 3, 5, 11, 79, 83, 89, 97, then I can express number less than 18680171730 uniquely. 10000000000 (1e10) can be expressed as 0,1,0,1,38,59,50,49 (1e10 mod 2, 3 ... , 97) which need not be expressed as special Big Integer class/struct which might save some bytes in some programming language.

Addition and substraction can be done directly using this representation.
Example:

```
(0,1,0,1,38,59,50,49)+(0,2,0,6,23,20,16,53) = 1e10 + 5000 
                                            = (0+0 mod 2, 1+2 mod 3, 0+0 mod 5, 1+6 mod 11, 38+23 mod 79, 59+20 mod 83, 50+16 mod 89, 49+53 mod 97)
```

Comment: Care to elaborate on that?

Comment: @Mayube I have added some explanation, but I doubt it is useless in most cases.

Comment: It's "remainder theorem".

Answer (score 6):

## Use String Padding (where possible)

If a large number includes a repeating digit at the beginning or end, you may be able to save bytes by using your one of your language's padding methods to construct a string of the number you're looking for, which you can then convert to an integer.

---

## Example

To generate the number `1111111111111111111111112` (25 bytes) in JavaScript (ES8):

```
+"2".padStart(25,1) // 19 bytes
```

Answer (score 3):

## Use Exponents

If your language has an exponent operator you might be able to use it to generate, if not the number you want, at least a number you can perform a simple calculation or 2 on to arrive at your number. Even without an operator, you may still be able to save bytes with a built-in function or method.

### Example

The [maximum safe integer in JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER) is `9007199254740991`, which is 16 digits long. In ES7, this can be calculated with the following 7 bytes:

```
2**53-1
```

The equivalent in ES6 and earlier, while the same length as the integer itself in this instance, demonstrates that using a more verbose method might not necessarily cost you any bytes.

```
Math.pow(2,53)-1
```

The above, though, may work out *shorter* if, for example, you already have `Math` aliased to a single character elsewhere in your code.

Answer (score 2):

## Use fractions in the place of float

Example: `1./3` in place of `0.333333333`